# External hard drive gets wrong user as owner

Tags: mount, permissions, external-hdd

When I attach my external hard drive, I cannot access it, because permissions are granted not to me but to another user.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, Maverick Meerkat.

1. Where do I report this as a bug? 
   1b. Is it a Ubuntu, or a Nautilus, or a Gnome problem?
2. Is there a solution for this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How did you mount your drive? Through Nautilus?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your `/etc/fstab` and of `sudo mount`.

Comment: @Apalala: `mount` without arguments does not need to be executed as root.

Comment: Have you tried `chown` or `chmod` in a terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a bug.  Either you have added an incorrect entry to your /etc/fstab, or you are mounting a filesystem that stores permissions and was created on another machine, and so the ownership information is not correct on yours.  If the former, then you need to chown the files to fix it, but this will of course, cause the same problem if you take the drive back to the other machine.

If you plan on moving the drive back and forth between machines, then you should use fat or ntfs.  UDF is also an option if you don't mind incompatibility with Windows since it refuses to mount a UDF filesystem on anything but optical media.

Comment: Psusi, thanks for your very clear answer. I'll look into /etc/fstab and will also inspect the filestystem and make sure it is using fat. Thanks!